# Azure SQL Server Database serverless "Auto-pause": How fast is resuming?

Tags: azure

In Azure, there is this "auto-pause" feature for serverless SQL Server Databases

[image: Auto-pause]

**Question:**

**Is there a quantitative measure (as opposed to qualitative) of how fast is "Resume" on a serverless SQL Database on Azure?**

I'm asking this because in my experience with DTU based tiers (S0, S1, S2, etc.), changing from one tier to another takes around 2-3 minutes, and within that interval all queries fail with timeout errors.
I want to know if "resuming" offers a similar experience (I wouldn't like the query that triggers the resume to be erratic)

Comment: Did you find any answer to this question? I am also interested and I don't find the answer

Comment: @Jorge No, nobody answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The latency to auto-resume and auto-pause a serverless database is generally order of 1 minute to auto-resume and 1-10 minutes after the expiration of the delay period to auto-pause.

According to the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql

From personal experience, a 1GB DB takes between 1-2 minutes to resume. During this time any queries, including the one that prompted the resume will timeout.